# WCF Concurrency, and OptimisticConcurrencyException

Tags: multithreading, wcf, entity-framework, concurrency, thread-safety

A WCF service is configured as

```
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple
```

I am using Entity Framework 3.1. Only with load tests and when I reached five concurrent users, I got OptimisticConcurrencyException.

I will either synchronize BLL.Update method.  Or use ConcurrencyMode.Single.  I cannot use ClientWins and  StoreWins techniques.

I will define a **private static Object instance** and lock on it to synchronize access to the method.  How I prevent one of the threads from being starved.  Is there a way to make the locking fair?  Is it a good idea to lock on a static reference?

Answer (score 1):

The exception that you are getting is OptimisticConcurrencyException. You are getting this since your transaction is using Optimistic Concurrency and 2 users are changing the same data.

There are atleast 3 ways to fix it:

- Design level: Why are different users changing the same data?
- Database level: use a transaction scope does not use optimistic concurrency for database access
- WCF level: use concurrency mode single for the WCF service

Your idea with the private static Object instance would have the same effect as setting the WCF service in single mode.

Comment: Agree but I am using perCall service context mode, thus I have a thread and a new service instance per client request.  using Single concurrency mode in this case is useless because I will lock on different instance objects

Comment: Also Ado.net and Entity framework only works with optimistic concurrency or no currency modes.